# Angular 2 ignoring http post request to RestApi

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I try to authenticate with the http post request from front-end side(Angular 2 in my case) to back-end(asp.net core web api). When Im sending the request it's proccessing and **throw back Status 200 OK**. But when after that I'm trying to get access to data which i can watch only after authentication, it throws an 404 code(unauthorized from server). Server and front-end side are on different ports.
**Though when I do that steps in Postman, it seems all right.** **Firstly** I do a http post request to get access: like this `post` `http://localhost:5000/api/account/login` `body: username:Admin password: admin` and **Secondly** simple do the http get request like this: `get` `http://localhost:5000/api/work` and that's worked**(In Postman and Advanced rest client for example)**.


**But in Angular** when I'm trying to do the same actions, Seems like **Angular forgets that i've done http post** and says me: "Man, you don't have access to info!".

Though in Network tab and in Postman http post returns Status 200 OK.
Guys, somebody please help, because it's a deggree project, which I have to take in about 10 days. Appriciate any help. Thanks. 
**Below is the code:**

**data.service.ts** file where post and get requests are located(getWorks() for getting data from RestApi, login() for login user):

```
getWorks(): Observable<IWork[]>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(this._baseUrl + 'work' ,{ headers: headers })
        .map((result: Response) => {
            return console.log(result);
             })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

login(user : User) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + 'account/login', JSON.stringify(user), { headers: headers })
        .map((result: Response) => {
            return result.json();
        }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**login.component.ts** file to take username and password, proccess it, and send to data.service.ts where methods getWorks() and login() request it to server:

```
login() : void {
    let _authenticationResult: OperationResult = new OperationResult(false, '');
    this.dataService.login(this._user).subscribe((result: any) => {
        _authenticationResult.succeeded = result.succeeded;
        _authenticationResult.message = result.message;

        if(_authenticationResult.succeeded) {
            this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage('Welcome ' + this._user.username + '!');
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this._user));
            this.router.navigate(['/list']);
        } else {
            this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(_authenticationResult.message);
        }
    }),
    error => console.error('Error: ' + error);
}

getData() {
    this.dataService.getWorks().subscribe(result => {
        this.works = result;
        this.subscribeToData();
    }, error => { 
        this.notificationService.printErrorMessage('Authentication reqired');
        this.utilityService.navigateToSignIn();
        console.error('Error: '+ error); });
}
```

**Update 1(thanks to @ArunKumaresh) but still doesnt work**

That is a **User class:**

```
export class User{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    constructor(username: string, password: string){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
login(user : any) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + 'account/login', JSON.stringify(user), { headers: headers })
            .map((result: Response) => {
                return result.json();
            }).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**Update 2(thanks the same person :) ) but still not**

```
login() : void {
        let _authenticationResult: OperationResult = new OperationResult(false, '');
        this.dataService.login({username: this._user.username, password: this._user.password}).subscribe((result: any) => {
            _authenticationResult.succeeded = result.succeeded;
            _authenticationResult.message = result.message;

            if(_authenticationResult.succeeded) {
                this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage('Welcome ' + this._user.username + '!');
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this._user));
                this.router.navigate(['/list']);
            } else {
                this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(_authenticationResult.message);
            }
        }),
        error => console.error('Error: ' + error);
    }
```

**Update 3. Thanks all of you guys, for helping with the issue, especially NotBad4U, man really helped me to solve that. I appriciate all your help, all of you guys.

[Here's the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786215/unexpected-end-of-json-input-angular-24-http-get-request/43806335#43806335)**

Comment: is this._user is a json ?

Comment: @ArunKumaresh No, it's an instance of a class User `_user: User;` and in `ngOnInit(){this._user = new User('', '');}`, but in `data.service.ts` `login(user){ return this.http.post(..., JSON.stringify(user))}` , i.e. instance of class User (_user) I send to `dataService.login(this._user)`, and is converting in `dataService` to `JSON`. I understand it so ;)

Comment: change your  service login(user : User) to login ( user : any ) and try

Comment: @ArunKumaresh the same( but, thanks for guess

Comment: what is User in login( user : User)

Comment: `export class User{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    constructor(username: string, password: string){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}`

Comment: can you update the question with what you have tried ?

Comment: your using JSON.stringify(user) in login but you are sending string values to the login service

Comment: but they are converting by `JSON.stringify(user)` to json, aren't they? and to server goes json

Comment: JSON.stringify will converted json to string

Comment: hm) How should I convert it to json? Or what should I do to server knows that this string is a username and password?

Comment: try like  this.dataService.login({ username : this.username, password : this.password })

Comment: @ArunKumaresh nothing changed :( same issue..

Comment: update your question with what you have tried with the login component class

Comment: @ArunKumaresh just updated, under Update 2 :)

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue. Your server needs to process OPTIONS requests properly (even when not authorized).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'll try, thanks for guessing :)